# Does Meteor Android APK contains images from public folder?

Tags: android, meteor, apk

I am newbie to Meteor as well as for android APK.
I just wanted to know whether Meteor Android APK contains images from public folder? or APK is made up of what components? I Don't want my apk to be much heavy i.e of bigger size (more than 20MB). As I am planning to build a offline Meteor Android APK and if public folder images are going to be there in offline Application then it will be a blunder for me as it will result in increased size apk. Please suggest. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: As far as i know, no, it doesn't android apk doesn't contain the images from public folder. I am not sure though, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

APK generated from meteor project contains full public folder.

If you want to check it out, You can do so using android studio's `profile or debug APK` option by opening your project APK.